# jQuery - each loop on multiple element types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've build pretty simple validator that will display my custom error message when someone tries to submit empty form. But I have some questions.

I have `.each()` loop on `:input` elements - how can I make it loop through `:input` and `textarea`?

I use `$(this).parent()` to get the form object of input, but how can I make sure that it is form, not some other element like div?

Code with comments

```
$('form input[type=submit]').click(function(){

    // First we get the form class
    var form = $(this).parent(); // How can I make sure that the form is selected, not some other parent like div?
    var formClass = $(form).attr('class');

    // Then remove every previous messages on this form
    $('.' + formClass + ' .validation-error').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });

    // Iterate through every input to find data that needs to be validated
    $('.' + formClass + ' :input').each(function(){ // How can I make this work with textareas as well as inputs without copying this whole each loop?

        // If it is marked as required proceed
        if ($(this).attr('required') == 'required'){

            // Getting current text and placeholder text
            var currentText = $(this).val();
            var placeholderText = $(this).attr('placeholder');

            // Replacing spaces to avoid empty requests
            currentText = currentText.replace(' ', '');
            placeholderText = placeholderText.replace(' ', '');

            // If current text is empty or same as placeholder proceed
            if (currentText == '' || currentText == placeholderText){

                // Get input position in order to place error message
                var inputPos = $(this).position();
                var left = inputPos.left + 200;
                var top = inputPos.top - 4;

                // Generate error message container and error message itself
                var errorMsg = '<div class="validation-error" style="position:absolute;left:' + left + 'px;top:' + top + 'px;"><- This</div>';

                // Appending error message to parent - form
                $(this).parent().append(errorMsg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Question 1:**

I have .each() loop on :input elements - how can I make it loop through :input and textarea?

**Answer:**

```
$(':input, textarea').
```

**Question 2:**

I use $(this).parent() to get the form object of input, but how can I make sure that it is form, not some other element like div?

**Answer:**

```
$(this).closest('form')
```

Comment: That will require sizzle and an unnecessary DOM traversal.

Comment: @AlienWebguy sizzle? For the multiple selector? I don't really know sizzle, but I've done both with out-of-the-box jquery.

Comment: SizzleJS is what JQuery uses for complex DOM traversal filtering. It's fast, but the idea is to try to avoid it and use native JS functions whenever possible. `$('#mydiv')` uses `getElementById()`, `$('.myclass')` uses `getElementsByClassName()`. Your selector will take some calculating. Not the end of the world, just something to be aware of. http://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I originally had the selector as `input`, but changed it to what was in the OP. Handy to know though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a comma to select multiple elements:

```
form.find("input,textarea").each(function(){...} );
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through both input and textarea:

```
$('.' + formClass + ' :input, .' + formClass + ' textarea').each...
```

To access parent form:

```
$(this).parents("form")
```